# Node.js plugin for more comfortable database queries

Tags: node.js, database, rest, sqlite

I'm working on a REST API. On one of my routes `/api/v1/user` you pass parameters via url, eg. `/api/v1/user?id=1&login=asdf`. I want my app to return user objects from SQLite database (I'm using `node-sqlite3` package to connect to db). In order to do this, I would have to make something like this (this is sqlite query which is later passed to function like db.all() and executed):

```
sql = `SELECT _id, login FROM Users WHERE _id={$req.swagger.params.id.value} AND login={req.swagger.params.id.value} ...
```

this is ultimately painful and doesn't really work, because all parameters in my url are optional (no parameters means return all users) and I have no idea how to make these parameters optional in that `sql` query string.
Long story short, I need module that would take an object, make a query out of that, so eg. from this object:

```
{
  id: 1,
  login: login1
}
```

it would create a query

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id=1 AND login=login1
```

of course with full customization of tables and columns chosen. If that's even possible, it would be nice if it could make queries appropriate to previousle chosen database.

EDIT: Forgot to add, I'm using swagger-express module as base framework of my application.

Answer (score 1):

So you need an ORM, i guess, try [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) or [Knex](http://knexjs.org/)

Comment: Damn, that's so simple that I feel ashamed for even asking that question. Thank you very much, now I know what to look for.